# What is the best file system to use with Xubuntu 11?

Tags: xubuntu

I really dont know what any of them mean. I know that NTFS and FAT and that they are associated for Windows....For Linux, which is the best File system that gets the best performance? I have it set to Ext 4.

Answer (score 3):

"best" is relative - there are some other filesystems that are *extrememly specialized* for special situations, but for general usage ext4 works nicely.

You can't use FAT or NTFS because they don't support the extended file attributes that Ubuntu needs (mainly a security thing).

Answer (score 2):

ext4 is good as per @jrg you cant use FAT or NTFS filesystem in ubuntu.
but you can read files from FAT and NTFS filesystem.